# Sort a GridView Column related to other Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, ado.net, sorting

i have a GridView bound to a DataView. 
Some columns in the DataView's table are foreignkeys to related tables(f.e. Customer). I want to enable sorting for these columns too, but all i can do is sorting the foreignkey(fiCustomer) and not the CustomerName.

I have tried this without success(" Cannot find column ERP_Customer.CustomerName "):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="ERP_Customer.CustomerName" >
```

A tried also the DataViewManager, but i've a problem to detect the table to sort:

```
    Dim daCharge As New ERPModel.dsERPTableAdapters.ERP_ChargeTableAdapter
    daCharge.Fill(dsERP.ERP_Charge)
    Dim viewManager As New DataViewManager(Me.dsERP)
    viewManager.DataViewSettings(dsERP.ERP_Charge).RowFilter = filter
    viewManager.DataViewSettings(dsERP.ERP_Charge).Sort = sort 'sort is the GridView's SortExpression
    Me.GrdCharge.DataSource = viewManager.CreateDataView(dsERP.ERP_Charge)
```

I have to apply the sort on a distinct table of the DataViewManager, but this table would differ on the related tables.
I have bound the TemplateColumns in Codebehind in RowDataBound-Event f.e.:

```
Dim LblCustomer As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("LblCustomer"), Label)
LblCustomer.Text = drCharge.ERP_CustomerRow.CustomerName 'drCharge inherits DataRow
```

What is the recommended way to sort a GridView on columns related to other tables? I could build a custom datatable with the customername instead of the foreignkey and bind this column to the TemplateField. But then my huge dataset in the model makes no sense anymore.

**EDIT:**
It seems that my question was not clear or too special.
Perhaps i can rephrase it in a more general term. 
I have a model with a Dataset. I'm binding one Datatable(ERP_Charge) from it to my GridView(actually i take a Dataview from that Table). In this Datatable are columns that are related to other Datatables in the Dataset(relations are defined). When i want to make the grid sortable its no problem on the columns that belong to ERP_Charge. But the columns with foreign keys to other table could  not be sorted because the Gridview shows f.e. not the CustomerID but the Customername. I get the Customername in RowDataBound.
Normally i would join the tables and add a Datacolumn for the Customername. Then i set this "virtual" Datatable as Datasource from the Gridview and i'm able to sort it. But i didnt want to create the datatables in the Page on the fly(it belongs into the model). **Do i have to define it in the dataset-Designer?** I thought it would be sufficient  to define the relationships in the dataset.

**UPDATE**: i had solved my sorting problems as below.

Regards

Comment: Read your question and have faced the same problem. Did you ever consider to use Linq to get Objects back and use them as a datasource?
I find it very handy to select a result that takes columns from multiple joined tables.

Comment: I must admit that linq is still a gap in my knowledge. Im afraid that it costs me too much time to change my model to use linq and of course learning the basics. But thanks anyway for the suggestion, i will think it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: i had solved my sorting problems in the following way: I changed my DataSet in the model and joined the related table to the Main-Table(ERP_Charge). I added the columns to the Datatable(f.e. CustomerName) that i want to sort. But i did that without saving it in the configuration wizard of the DataAdapter, because that would delete all Update-,Delete- and InsertCommands. Hence i changed only the SelectCommand with the one that was generated from the Wizard. Therefore i kept the benefit of my Datamodel with the ability to sort for columns of related tables. Maybe queries are a little slower now because of the joins but it works for me.